# Why does my GDB automatically step into functions?

Tags: linux, gdb, frame

I try to debug some C++ code with GDB on Linux. For instance

```
Handle xxx = xxxxx;
if (xxx === ...){
    ...
}
```

When I use "n" to go through the code, GDB will automatically step into Handle class's constructor. Sometimes it also steps into normal functions.

It seems that it doesn't happen on [HP-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-UX).

How can I prevent GDB doing this? Let it just step over the constructor.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?